# PHP Upload images

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload a file to a remote server using PHP `move_uploaded_file` but the file is not showing in my directory on the server. I've checked my code plenty but I cannot seem to find the error. This is my code.

```
$pid = mysql_insert_id();
$newname = "$pid.jpg";
$uploaddir = "../inventory_images/$newname";
$tmp = $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $uploaddir);
```

Thanks.

I ran the given code `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_FILES); exit;` and this is the output:

```
array(1) {
  ["fileField"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "101656b.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpZopcDK"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(16652)
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: Please add this line above the `$pid` line: `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_FILES); exit;`. Run the code, and post the output in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if that directory is writable. (ask provider to set it writable or use FTP access client, such as [Cyberduck](http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/chmod-ftp.phtml) to set directory writable yourself)

Suggested to use absolute path, thou relative will work. See the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable.

Php should refer this issue in error log. "[..] was unable to put files" (error doesn't states the reason, that directory is set to read-only.. )

p.s. instead of function *move_uploaded_file* function *copy* will work

Comment: Thank you. It was a file directory permissions issue. I really should have thought of that. It works now. Much appreciated.